# Is there a way to Get a Project and put it into a specific folder and Label it(tie it to a version #) in TFS?

Tags: file, tfs, project, label, extract

I was wondering if there is some easy way in TFS to get a specific project and put it into a destination folder of your choosing and put a label on it or version number. If the project can be zipped, that would be even better. I want to be able to go into VS, right click on a folder or file, click Get Specific Version..., choose Label in the type drop down list, and Browse for the label of the project I want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform above tasks from Visual Studio by installing Visual Studio Team Explorer.

Comment: I have Visual Studio Team Explorer, but how do I do it though?

Comment: Map your specific folder to Workspace, perform Get Specific version(open the Project in Visual Studio, Right Click the folder or file in Solution Explorer-->Click Get Specific Version) and then apply label(File-->Source Control-->Label-->Apply Label).In New Label Window, Choose Version option as Workspace Version and specify your Workspace.